# When is $f(A^C)=(f(A))^C$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

While reading through baby Rudin, I often come across the statements, for $f$ continuous

$A\subset f^{-1}(f(A))$ with $A=f^{-1}(f(A))$ when $f$ is injective

$f(f^{-1}(B))\subset B$ with $B=f(f^{-1}(B))$ when $f$ is surjective

$f^{-1}(Z^C)=(f^{-1}(Z))^{C}$ when $f$ is bijective

However, no rationale that I can find is given for these statements. Are they true, are the conditions necessary, and why?

Comment: You can prove them!  For example: To prove $E \subset F$, let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $E$ and prove that $x \in F$.

Comment: You can find these relations in almost any undergraduate level real analysis, set theory, abstract algebra, topology, etc. text, where usually one or more is proved and others are left as exercises. If you need existing proofs (and not just write your own), the quickest way would simply be to flip through such books in a university library. You can probably can find find proofs for every statement in less than 5 minutes once you're at the shelves. See also section 2 of [these notes](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/interactions+of+images+and+pre-images+with+unions+and+intersections).

Comment: On the other hand, maybe your problem is in writing proofs?  Then you may need a book on that first.  Say, *How to Read and Do Proofs* by Daniel Solow or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one proof for you.  See if you can do the others.

Claim: $A\subset f^{-1}(f(A))$.
Let $x \in A$.  We must show $ \in f^{-1}(f(A))$.

Now $x \in A$, so $f(x) \in f(A)$ by definition of $f(A)$.  The definition for $x \in f^{-1}(E)$ is: $f(x) \in E$.  In this case, that definition with $E = f(A)$ shows that $x \in f^{-1}(f(A))$.  This completes the proof.

Comment: What I don’t understand is the specification that they are equal only if f is injective. Why would they not otherwise be equal?

Comment: [I doesn't say "only if", it says "when", meaning "if". ]  Consider the non-injective function $f(x) = x^2$ mapping $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$.  If $A = \{2\}$, then what is $f^{-1}(f(A))$ ??